# Feathers js - google login lead to delete of existing user

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Generate google access token in Frontend(I am using React library `react-google-login`)

2.Login using `local` strategy using email A(User A)

POST /authentication
body

```
{
    "strategy": "local",
    "email": "{{email A}}",
    "password": "{{password}}"
}
```

3.Login as User B using `google` strategy of using jwt token(generated in step 2) in Authorization of account A

POST /authentication
body

```
{
    "strategy": "google",
    "access_token": "<google access token in step 1>"
}
```

#### Expected behavior

User B created.

#### Actual behavior

User B created, **while User A is deleted in Database**

### Code

authentication.js

```
const { AuthenticationService, AuthenticationBaseStrategy, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
const { discard, iff, isProvider, lowerCase, keep } = require('feathers-hooks-common')

const { OAuthStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
class GoogleStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {

  async getEntityData(profile) {
    // this will set 'googleId'
    const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile);
    const existingOauthEntity = await super.findEntity(profile)

    // Check if user already exist
    if(existingOauthEntity){
      return {
        ...baseData
      }
    }else{
      return {
        ...baseData,
        email: profile.email,
      };
    }
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());
  authentication.register('google', new GoogleStrategy());
 
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());

  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {},
    after: {
      create: [
        discard('authentication')
      ]
    }
   });
};
```

users.hook.js

```
const { iff, isProvider, keep, required, disallow, disablePagination, preventChanges, sequelizeConvert} = require('feathers-hooks-common');
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;
const checkPermissions = require('feathers-permissions');
const errors = require('@feathersjs/errors');

const {
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ 
      sequelizeConvert({
        isEmailVerified: 'boolean',
      }),
    ],
    find: [
      iff(isProvider('external'),
        authenticate('jwt'),
        checkPermissions({
          roles: [ 'superadmin', 'admin'],
          error: true,
        })
    )
    ],
    get: [
      iff(isProvider('external'),
        iff(!(context => {return (context.params.authStrategies[0] === 'google')}),
          authenticate('jwt'),
          checkPermissions({
            roles: [ 'admin'],
            error: true,
          })
        )
      )
    ],
    create: [
      iff(isProvider('external'),
        iff((context => !context.params.authStrategies) || (context => !(context.params.authStrategies[0] === 'google')),
          authenticate('jwt'),
          checkPermissions({
            roles: [ 'admin'],
            error: true,
          }),
          required('email', 'password'),
          hashPassword('password'),
        )
      )
    ],
    update: [disallow()],
    patch: [
      iff(isProvider('external'),
      preventChanges(true, [
        'id',
        'password',
        'passwordResetEmailToken',
        'passwordResetToken',
        'passwordResetRequestedAt',
        'passwordResetExpiresAt',
      ]),
      authenticate('jwt'),
      checkPermissions({
        roles: ['admin'],
        error: false,
      }),
      )
    ],
  },
  after: {
    all: [ 
      sequelizeConvert({
        isEmailVerified: 'boolean',
      }),
      protect(
        'password',
        'passwordResetEmailToken'
      )
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [disallow('external')],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

};
```